# Main Form changes size after every build

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have been given a VB project by a collegue to import into visualstudio professional to add a setup project to. The project was originally a 2003 projet I don't konw which version, VB express 2003 possibly, then imported into vb express 2008 and now professional 2010.

The problem is every time I rebuild the project without doing anything else the main form changes its size. It shrinks in height by about 40. hit build again and it shrinks again.

Any idea what this might be and can it be fixed or will I have to create a brand new project and import the source files with all the risk that that entails.

Comment: Nobody can answer you without seeing the code and the problem. Add code example + screenshot of the problem. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what code are you expecting, it is auto generated.

Comment: Your problem is too general. It will be very difficult to find the root of the problem, unless somebody had exactly the same problem by chance. And even in this case it will be hard to help.

Comment: The line that changes is Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(320, 479)

Comment: the next time it is The line that changes is Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(320, 459). without changing anything else pressing rebuild generates a different second number. I can't help but be general, I just wondered if any one else had a similar problem to help me narrow down the search of where to look. Then maybe I can upload the relevant section of code. Otherwise it would have to be the whole projet. At the end of the day the problem is with the graphical form designer which generates some 1000 line of code. My collegue suspects its the mscomm object but I don't see why

Comment: Smells like a problem with MainMenu.  Delete it from the form and check if that solves the problem.  Replace with MenuStrip.

Comment: Thanks Hans
That seems to be the problem. Just deleted the menu and the window now stays the same size. Just need to add it back in again.

Comment: Any idea why the menu should affect this?

Answer (score 0):

Recently i saw a thread in a german forum, where someone described a similar/the same effect. There it had to do with a manually set font of the form/controls in conjunction with the AutoScale property which was set to "Font". The solution of this problem was to set the AutoScale property to DPI instead of "Font".

Hope this helps you too.
(http://forum.chip.de/basic/steuerlemente-start-visual-studio-verkleinert-1587819.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same thing in VS2010 with C# and the form still resizes itself even with AutoScale property change. The Font is the default font and hasn't been changed. (Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt)

I made a new form base class:

```
public class form2 : Form
{
}
```

After basing my form off this, it stopped resizing itself.

Since the above code looks like it doesn't do anything, I made my form base off of Form again, and the resizing reappeared.

If I leave the form based off the altered base:

public partial class frmMain : form2
{
...
}

it doesn't resize!

I commented the menu code out and resizing stopped - even when based off of Form instead of form2. If I use a MenuStrip instead of a MainMenu it also works as intended.
(I'm not even sure where MainMenu came from. It was in the toolbox when I drug it on to the form, but it isn't there now)

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that resizing effect after I changed the form property ShowInTaskbar to false and FormBorderStyle to none. It didn't happen with FormBorderStyle sizable. I could only avoid the effect while keeping the FormBorderStyle to none with setting ShowInTaskbar to true.